Sending Structured Logs to Pytest and Pretty-Printed Logs to the Console
I am writing a Pytest suite that generates a lot of logs with structured data from Structlog, but they are very noisy when printed to the console. I use the JSON report plugin, and I want to dump the  structured data to that. But, I also want to show the unstructured data in the console.
The problem is that it seems like Pytest's log output comes directly from stdout, so I can't have separate log streams. That means, essentially, that if I make a quality-of-life change like adding colors to the console output or formatting my data differently, then those will affect my structured data. Other examples of things I might like to do would be removing the timestamp from the console, but still retaining that in the JSON data.
The question here is, does anyone know of a way I can send different data streams to the Pytest log and the console? That would allow me to have a nice console experience for me, but also keep writing structured data to the report.
I have tried writing using the ConsoleRenderer to format my console logs, which works great. But, that makes it so the JSON report no longer contains the raw JSON log lines that are otherwise machine readable.
I'm basically trying to merge two approaches. The first is the approach that makes the console output look good. That is basically the same as the Structlog hello world:
import structlog
log = structlog.get_logger()
log.info("hello, %s!", "world", key="value!", more_than_strings=[1, 2, 3]) 

The second approach is the one that makes the JSON report machine-readable. That is achieved by adding the JSONRenderer processor to the configuration above.
